# React Router 3, exactly match against query param

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In React Router 3, how do you match exactly against a route containing query params?

Something like this,

```
<Route path="about?qs1=:qs&qs2=:qs2" component={About} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query params are not part of a route in that sense. You will need to check for them inside your component, for example like this:

```jsx
class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.location.query.qs1 ? 'Correct route!' : 'Invalid route!'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You could also check for the query params inside `componentDidMount` and redirect your users to a different route (e.g. 404). [Read more about Route Matching in the official docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md).

Comment: Alright thanks, just that it is less obvious to see that `qs1` is needed. They will need to go inside the component to see this scenario. Another thing is that if I wanna require dynamically(between correct route and invalid route), I would need another wrapper.
Thanks for the answer.