# ReactJS dynamic route without "/"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am doing email verification where the user clicks a system generated link i.e: `www.mydomain.com/verify?token=982db6fefde1fb` using `<Route path="verify?token=:id" component={Verify} />` but I can't seem to get dynamic id working if there is no `/` before `:id` it throws a router error

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "/verify?token=982db6fefde1fb25cc0a8cd82dae783ff5519b3f023463c1" did not match any routes.
```

How do I create a dynamic `:id` route without using `/`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router 3, exactly match against query param](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334284/react-router-3-exactly-match-against-query-param)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the route like

```
<Route path="verify" component={Verify} />
```

and now in the `Verify` component you can fetch the query parameter like

```
this.props.location.query.token
```